# This series is known? $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{\prod _{i=1}^n\left(2i-1\right)}$

Tags: power-series

This series is known?
I was solving a differential equation by power series and my solution involves that series

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{\prod _{i=1}^n\left(2i-1\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you for edit people

Comment: The coefficient is screaming double factorial to me. Maybe that is an approach?

There is a pretty cool identity that says $\Gamma(n + \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}$ where $(2n-1)!!$ is precisely the denominator you have there.

Comment: I'm gonna check thanks

Comment: Hint: multiply numerator and denominator by $\prod_{i=1}^n (2i) = 2^n n!$.

Comment: ^ Yeah this is way more promising than the double factorial rabbit hole haha.

Comment: I think the clue you need is to write $\prod_{i=1}^n \,(2i - 1)$ as $2^n(1/2)_n$ where $(\cdot)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol. This'll let you cancel a few things, and I bet will suggest a ${}_1F_1(1; 1/2; z)$-like hypergeometric series, but work through it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/proving-formula-for-product-of-first-n-odd-numbers I apply that but I obtain  k!/(2k)! in the process of replace

Comment: \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\left(2x\right)^{2k-1}\frac{k!}{\left(2k\right)!}

Comment: Context-wise, It might help to show how this came up. What equation were you solving?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100264/solving-y-2xy-2y-0-using-power-series I am solving this differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)\right)}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i(2i-1))}\\
&=\frac{2^nn!}{(2n)!}.
\end{align}$$
So your sum is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}(2x)^{2n-1}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{2^{2n}n!}{(2n)!}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.$$
Let $t_n=\frac{2^{2n}n!}{(2n)!}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}$, so that $f(x)=x\sum_{n\ge0}t_n$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}&=\frac{\frac{2^{2n+2}(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+3}}{\frac{2^{2n}n!}{(2n)!}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}}\\
&=(2x)^2\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\\
&=(2x)^2\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}\frac{n+1}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{n+3/2}\frac{x^2}{n+1},
\end{align}$$
so we may write
$$t_n=\frac{(1)_n}{(3/2)_n}\frac{(x^2)^n}{n!}t_0,$$
where $$(z)_n=\frac{\Gamma(z+n)}{\Gamma(z)}=z(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+n-1).$$
Since $t_0=1$, we have
$$\sum_{n\ge0}t_n=\,_1F_1(1;\tfrac32;x^2),$$
and thus
$$f(x)=x\,_1F_1(1;\tfrac32;x^2),$$
where
$$_pF_q(a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(a_1)_n\cdots(a_p)_n}{(b_1)_n\cdots(b_q)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
is the generalized hypergeometric function.

Anyway, for $\Re(b)>\Re(a)>0$, we have the integral representation
$$_1F_1(a;b;z)=\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b-a)}\int_0^1e^{zt}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-1}dt,$$
from [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/07/01/01/0001/).
Using this,
$$f(x)=\frac{x\Gamma(\tfrac32)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\tfrac12)}\int_0^1\frac{e^{x^2 t}}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt=\frac{x}{2}\int_0^1\frac{e^{x^2t}}{\sqrt{1-t}}dt.$$
Then write $z=\sqrt{1-t}$, so that $-2dz=\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t}}$, and
$$f(x)=x\int_0^1e^{x^2(1-z^2)}dz=xe^{x^2}\int_0^1e^{-(xz)^2}dz.$$
Finally, writing $u=xz$, we have
$$f(x)=e^{x^2}\int_0^{x}e^{-u^2}du.$$
Recalling the definition of the [Error Function $\mathrm{erf}(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), we have
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{x^2}\mathrm{erf}(x).$$
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is correct I've verified

Answer (score 1):

My Wolfram Mathematica code

```
Sum[2^(n-1) x^(2 n-1)/Product[2i-1, {i,1,n}],
   {n,1,Infinity}] // InputForm
```

returns the result

```
(E^x^2*Sqrt[Pi]*Erf[x])/2
```

which is

$$ f(x) := \frac12 \sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} \text{erf}(x) $$

and where $\,\text{erf}(x)\,$ is the
[Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). The function $\,f(x)\,$ satisfies the ordinary differential equation

$$ f'(x) = 1 + 2\,xf(x). $$

By the way,  this equation is the basis for an iterative recursion
for the truncated power series of the function using

$$ f_0(x) := O(x), \quad f_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^x 1 + 2\,tf_n(t)\,dt. $$

The function also has another property. Define the differential operator

$$ T[ f(x) ] := e^{x^2} \frac{d}{dx} \left(e^{-x^2} f(x)\right)
= f'(x) - 2\,x f(x). $$
Then your function satisfies $\, T[ f(x) ] = 1.$

Comment: What is erf(x)?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\prod _{i=1}^n\left(2i-1\right)=(2n-1)!!\tag1
$$
Therefore, the sum you are looking for is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!!}\tag2
$$
For $u\ge0$, let
$$
f(u)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2u)^{n-\frac12}}{(2n-1)!!}\tag3
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
f'(u)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2u)^{n-\frac12}}{(2n-1)!!}\tag{4a}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2u)^{n-\frac32}}{(2n-3)!!}\tag{4b}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2u}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2u)^{n-\frac12}}{(2n-1)!!}\tag{4c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2u}}+f(u)\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: differentiate $(3)$
$\text{(4b)}$: differentiate term by term
$\text{(4c)}$: pull the $n=1$ term out front and re-index
$\text{(4d)}$: apply $(3)$

Therefore, rearranging $(4)$ and multiplying by the integrating factor of $e^{-u}$, we get
$$
\left(e^{-u}f(u)\right)'=e^{-u}f'(u)-e^{-u}f(u)=\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{2u}}\tag5
$$
Integrating, noting that $f(0)=0$, yields
$$
\begin{align}
e^{-u}f(u)
&=\int_0^u\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{2t}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{6a}\\
&=\sqrt2\int_0^{\sqrt{u}}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{6b}\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{\pi/2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{u}\right)\tag{6c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a)}$: integrate $(5)$
$\text{(6b)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t^2$
$\text{(6c)}$: apply the [definition of $\operatorname{erf}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

Thus, $(6)$ yields
$$
f(u)=e^u\sqrt{\pi/2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{u}\right)\tag7
$$
Therefore, we can apply $(3)$ and $(7)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!!}
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}f\!\left(x^2\right)\tag{8a}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x)\tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$
Since the series and $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ are odd functions, we can remove the positivity restriction.